# Compute $\int \int(a^2-x^2)\ dx\ dy$ taken over half the circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$ in the positive quadrant.

Tags: integration

Since it is given as positive quadrant, I took the limits as follows,
w.r.t. x from 0 to a & w.r.t y from 0 to root of $$(a^2-x^2)$$.
I proceeded with that & finally substituted $x=a\sin(\theta)$. The answer which I got was $(3(a^4)π)/16$. But the actual answer is $(3a^4)/8$. I don't know where I am making a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The question refers to a half circle and you are integrating over a quarter of  a circle. Perhaps the intended region is $\{(x,y):x \geq 0, x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 1$ in which case $y$ will vary from $-\sqrt {a^{2}-x^{2}}$ to $\sqrt {a^{2}-x^{2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\limits_{x=0}^a \int\limits_{y=0}^\sqrt{a^2-x^2} (a^2 -x^2)\ dy\ dx = \frac{3 \pi a^4}{16}$$